# How to obtain SEs or CIs for predicted probabilities for Heckman models

Tags: r, prediction, predict

Question: How to get SEs (or confidence intervals) for predicted probabilities from Heckman model

Reproducible example using Mroz87 dataset contained within sampleSelection package to get predicted probability of lfp (labor force participation) for women with kids and without kids:

```
library(sampleSelection)

data("Mroz87")
Mroz87$kids <- (Mroz87$kids5 + Mroz87$kids618 > 0)

ml1 <- selection(lfp ~ age + I(age^2) + kids + huswage + educ,
                 log(wage) ~ educ + exper + I(exper^2) + city, method = "2step", data = Mroz87)

ndata <- data.frame(
  age = median(Mroz87$age),
  kids = c(0, 1),
  huswage = median(Mroz87$huswage),
  educ = median(Mroz87$educ)
)

pred_probs <- cbind(ndata, probs = predict(ml1, ndata, part = "selection", type = "response"))

# Predicted prob of lfp (labor force participation): 
# with kids (kids = 1): 59%; 
# without kids (kids = 0): 73%

# Upper and lower bounds?
```